# Heroku Pstgres Can't acess tables in DB

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have a simple blog hosted in Heroku developed using Python-Flask and DB PostgreSQL.
I wanted to see the no of users registered and their username in my blog
but when i try select query using psql user table showing only one column with the username from my credentials like this

```
DATABASE=> select * from user;
      user      
----------------
 qvnlbmnhxnrzpv
(1 row)
```

Also i have a free tier plan on Heroku.Hobby-dev in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user` is a reserved word, which gives the name of the sql user logged on.  If you have an actual table with that name, you need to put it in double quotes to access it.

```
select * from "user";
```